# How to align images besides each other such that they get evenly distributed along the width of the page?

Tags: html, image, css

I need to do the following:

1. Align four icons of equal sizes of (128x128) besides each other.
2. I need those icons to be distributed evenly according to the width of the page.
3. I need those icons to be at the center of the page.
4. Those icons must have captions associated with them and of course centralized on the page evenly as well.

I started working on it like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>INSERT_IMAGE1_URL_HERE</td>
<td>INSERT_IMAGE2_URL_HERE </td>
<td>INSERT_IMAGE3_URL_HERE </td>
<td>INSERT_IMAGE4_URL_HERE </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>INSERT_IMAGE1_CAPTION_HERE </td>
<td>INSERT_IMAGE2_CAPTION_HERE </td>
<td>INSERT_IMAGE3_CAPTION_HERE </td>
<td>INSERT_IMAGE4_CAPTION_HERE </td>
</tr>
<tr>
</table>
```

But I was too far from getting the above result. The center tag is not helping much and the captions are getting messed up.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/128x128">
      <figcaption>Caption 1</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/128x128">
      <figcaption>Caption 2</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/128x128">
      <figcaption>Caption 3</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/128x128">
      <figcaption>Caption 4</figcaption>
    </figure>

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

**CSS**

```
body {margin:0;}
.container {}
figure { margin:0; width:25%; float:left; text-align: center; }
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pE42k/)**

Comment: Thanks man for that! I highly appreciate it. You used HTML5 here with the figure and figcaption. Really cool stuff. Thanks